# Quickbooks Online - Cannot get LinkedTxn detail

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I created an `Expense` record and linked to an `Invoice`. When i import `Invoice` object through API, it has linked transaction as below.

```
"LinkedTxn":[{
     "TxnId":"1356",               //Id of Expense
     "TxnType":"ReimburseCharge"   //Type showing as ReimburseCharge
}]
```

In [Quickbooks online docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/invoice), it is mentiond as

> Links to expenses incurred on behalf of the customer are returned in
>   the response with `LinkedTxn.TxnType` set to `ReimbCharge`, `ChargeCredit`
>   or `StatementCharge` corresponding to billable customer expenses of type
>   `Cash`, `Delayed Credit`, and `Delayed Charge`, respectively. Links to these
>   types of transactions are established within the QuickBooks UI, only,
>   and are available as read-only at the API level.
>
> Use `LinkedTxn.TxnLineId` as the ID in a separate read request for the
>   specific resource to retrieve details of the linked object.

In response it is showing TxnType as `ReimburseCharge`, but I didn't see any object like that in api explorer or docs. I don't know what type of object to request with id. I tried with `Purchase`, `PurchaseOrder`, `Bill` etc. but not of the request returned expected expense record.

Please help on how to access this Expense record with linked transaction id through api.

**Invoice JSON:**
Invoice line with description **Printing paper** is the expense linked in this invoice.

```
{
   "Invoice":{
      "Id":"1358",
      "LinkedTxn":[
         {
            "TxnId":"1356",
            "TxnType":"ReimburseCharge"
         }
      ],
      "Line":[
         {
            "Id":"1",
            "LineNum":1,
            "Description":"Printing paper",
            "DetailType":"DescriptionOnly",
            "DescriptionLineDetail":{

            }
         },
         {
            "Id":"3",
            "LineNum":2,
            "Description":"Magazine Monthly",
            "Amount":100.0,
            "DetailType":"SalesItemLineDetail",
            "SalesItemLineDetail":{
               "ItemRef":{
                  "value":"19",
                  "name":"Publications:Magazine Monthly"
               },
               "UnitPrice":100,
               "Qty":1,
               "TaxCodeRef":{
                  "value":"NON"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "Amount":250.0,
            "DetailType":"SubTotalLineDetail",
            "SubTotalLineDetail":{

            }
         }
      ],
      "Balance":250.0
   }
}
```

[image: Quickbooks Online Image]

Answer (score 1):

The docs are a little confusing on this point - unfortunately, the second paragraph

> Use `LinkedTxn.TxnLineId` as the ID in a separate read request for the specific resource to retrieve details of the linked object.

is a generic paragraph that appears for docs on every `Ref` type, but shouldn't appear here. It's impossible to access these transactions via the API. More detail available [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0200_dev_guides/accounting/0030_manage_linked_transactions#/Notes_about_linked_transactions_in_invoice_objects).